# Vary output caching on usercontrol by clientID

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0, outputcache

I have a user control which I would like to use output caching on, but it is used several times with different data.

I thought about using VaryByCustom and try to receive the ClientID of the control, but haven't been able to find a way.

Is there a way to output cache a usercontrol based on the ClientID, or another way to identify it by its position in the DOM?

**Update:**
I have tried to add a hidden field and set the output caching. For the example I have set the value of the hidden field to Datetime.Now, but it still displays the same usercontrol, and not two who are different by the content.

```
<%@ OutputCache VaryByControl="hidMyField" Duration="120" %>
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidMyField" Value="<%= Datetime.Now.ToString() %>"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the way could be to have a server side hidden field on the control, push the user control's client ID into it and then use [VaryByControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.outputcacheparameters.varybycontrol.aspx) parameter with hidden field's ID.

For more information/options, see [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4he1ds5%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) that discusses the same problem.

**EDIT**
Using `Datetime.Now.ToString()` is not a good idea for two reasons! If you see the actual value for various controls, you will find it to be the same because `ToString` will have value up to seconds - all your control instances on the page will have almost same date/time value probably differing in milli-seconds which will give same `ToString()` value.
Second issue is that `DateTime.Now` is non-deterministic. For caching to work, you need to have deterministic value (a value that does not changes in repeated calls) - otherwise for every page request, you will have a different value which will invalidate the cache. I suggest putting user control's  client id as a value. Yet another way would be expose a property in user control and set it to running number such as 1,2,3.. from the page.

Comment: I have tried to do what said, but it didn't work (See updated question).

Comment: This solution only seems to work with postback data? I had the problem with same control added twice to a page, but with different settings. If the control had been added in a normal way (<Control id=...>) it wouldn't have been a problem, but my controls were added in a loop with LoadControl, which made me fall on a bug in asp.net. See more info and workaround here:http://devnet.kentico.com/Blogs/Martin-Hejtmanek/April-2009/How-to-dynamically-load-partially-cached-controls.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Nest them inside another user control and put instances of that where ever you want it to be cached.